# want text to display when submit input is pressed and 3 seconds later it redirects to Index.html

Tags: javascript, html, wait, show-hide

Need this site to show some text when the submit input is pressed and when the text shows then a timer starts (3 seconds) to then go back to ../index.html

HTML

```
<label for="fname">Fornavn</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Ditt fornavn.." required>

<label for="lname">Etternavn</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Ditt etternavn.." required>

<label for="country">Fylke</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="australia">Agder</option>
  <option value="canada">Rogaland</option>
  <option value="usa">Viken</option>
</select>

<label for="subject">Tema</label>
<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Hva gjelder det.." style="height:200px" required></textarea>

<input id="submitNew" type="submit" value="Send inn">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="success" hidden> 
  <p><center><strong>Vellykket</strong></center>Du har Vellykket Sendt inn</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("success");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function formSubmit(form) {
    document.getElementById("submitNew").value = "Loading...";
    setTimeout(function() {
        form.submit();
    }, 3000);  // 3 seconds
    return false;
}
```

want success text to display when submit button is pressed and 3 seconds later it redirects to Index.html
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First wrap your code in a form tag with an id and action="index.html"

```
<form id="form1" action="index.html">
<!-- your html fields and buttons here -->
</form>
```

Then, in your script, assign form to a variable and add a listener for the submit.

Note that e.preventDefault() will avoid your form to submit immediately, then call your function to display the message and setTimeout to submit.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');

// Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("submitNew").value = "Loading...";
  myFunction1();
  setTimeout(function() {
      form.submit();
  }, 3000);  // 3 seconds
  return false;

});
```

Comment: Im really sorry but you want me to wrap in all the code or just the code I showed here?
I added a picture of all my HTML
if you need any more information Please let me know and Im a noob when it comes to js and Im okay-good at html. cant too much about form tho.

Comment: So, your code is already inside a form tag, no need to change this, but you can set the action as I said above. 
In your .js you can use a listener and when the form is submitted it'll wait and do the stuff you want

Comment: Check this fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/elgsantos/ndrjqumL/4/
I added also a verification if display is empty.

Comment: Thank you, I could never(in time for deadline) have figured this out on my own.